# Python - Overlay more than 3 WAV files end to end

Tags: python, audio, wave

I am trying to overlap the end of 1 wav file with 20% of the start of the next file. Like this, there are a variable number of files to overla (usually around 5-6).

I have tried using pydub implementation be expanding the following for overlaying 2 wav files :

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/path/to/file1.wav")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/path/to/file1.wav")

# mix sound2 with sound1, starting at 70% into sound1)
output = sound1.overlay(sound2, position=0.7 * len(sound1))

# save the result
output.export("mixed_sounds.wav", format="wav")
```

And wrote the following program :

```
for i in range(0,len(files_to_combine)-1):
    if 'full_wav' in locals():
        prev_wav = full_wav
    else:
        prev = files_to_combine[i]
        prev_wav = AudioSegment.from_wav(prev)

    next = files_to_combine[i+1]        
    next_wav = AudioSegment.from_wav(next)

    new_wave = prev_wav.overlay(next_wav,position=len(prev_wav) - 0.3 * len(next_wav))
    new_wave.export('partial_wav.wav', format='wav')

    full_wav = AudioSegment.from_wav('partial_wav.wav')
```

However, when I look at the final wave file, only the first 2 files in the list `files_to_combine` were actually combined and not the rest. The idea was to continuously rewrite `partial_wav.wav` until it finally contains the full wav file of the near end to end overlapped sounds. To debug this, I stored the `new_wave` in different files for every combination. The first wave file is the last: it only shows the first 2 wave files combined instead of the entire thing. Furthermore, I expected the `len(partial_wav)` for every iteration to gradually increase. Hoever, this remains the same after the first combination:

```
partial_wave : 237
partial_wave : 237
partial_wave : 237
partial_wave : 237
partial_wave : 237
```

**MAIN QUESTION**

How do I overlap the end of one wav file (about the last 30%) with the beginning of the next for more than 3 wave files?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can just keep on cascading `audiosegments` until your final segment as below.

Working Code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

sound1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("SineWave_440Hz.wav")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_wav("SineWave_150Hz.wav")
sound3 = AudioSegment.from_wav("SineWave_660Hz.wav")


# mix sound2 with sound1, starting at 70% into sound1)
tmpsound = sound1.overlay(sound2, position=0.7 * len(sound1))


# mix sound3 with sound1+sound2, starting at 30% into sound1+sound2)
output = tmpsound .overlay(sound3, position=0.3 * len(tmpsound))

play(output)
output.export("mixed_sounds.wav", format="wav")
```